# How to correctly add NSComboBox to view-based NSTableView in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview, nscombobox

I'm basically asking how do you correctly add a Combo Box to a Table View with correct layout i.e. so that appears as if you were adding a ComboBox cell to a cell-based Table View. Currently when I add it to the Table Cell View it doesn't fit (bottom half chopped off) and doesn't behave as its supposed i.e. focus ring is messed up, arrows messed up, not aligned correctly.

I have searched the net couple of times over and funny enough I haven't found an answer to this question. If I don't find a solution I might have return to good old cell-based table views.

Answer (score 0):

If the combo box doesn't fit, you need to increase the height of the NSTableCellView. This is done in Interface Builder or, if implemented, in the NSTableViewDelegate method tableView:heightOfRow:.